# Mate actionscript only version, does it exist?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mate

Hey there, I'm looking into using Mate, but the projects I work on do not require the majority of the functionality of the Flex framework. My workmate said that he heard of an Actionscript version, but I can find no information on the main site about this, only that they have removed some dependencies on the Flex framework.

Does anyone know if their is an effort to move Mate towards a state that it can be used without the Flex framework?

Comment: I probably confused Mate with Prana (http://www.pranaframework.org) - that does have an as3 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mate uses tags heavily, therefore it has a dependency on Flex. There are some ways to use tags without the Flex framework, but there are places in Mate where we use framework classes. It would take some effort to try to remove those dependencies, and while it is something that we want to investigate, I don't think it will happen soon, unless somebody else takes over that task :)